# UnexpectedType error to refactoring

Tags: rascal

I'm having a problem while trying to refactor an `if/else statement` in a `switch statement`. The grammar used is Java 8, according to the syntax below:

**If else statement**

```
syntax IfThenStatement = "if" "(" Expression ")" Statement ;

syntax IfThenElseStatement = "if" "(" Expression ")" StatementNoShortIf "else" Statement ;

syntax IfThenElseStatementNoShortIf = "if" "(" Expression ")" StatementNoShortIf "else" StatementNoShortIf ;
```

**Switch statement**

```
syntax SwitchStatement = "switch" "(" Expression ")" SwitchBlock ; 

syntax SwitchBlock = "{" SwitchBlockStatementGroup* SwitchLabel* "}" ;

syntax SwitchBlockStatementGroup = SwitchLabels BlockStatements ;

syntax SwitchLabels = SwitchLabel+ ; 

syntax SwitchLabel = "case" ConstantExpression ":" 
                   | "default" ":" 
                   ;
```

I'm using the following code to perform the refactoring:

```
CompilationUnit refactorIfElseStatement(CompilationUnit unit) =  visit(unit) {
    case (IfThenElseStatement) `if (<Identifier idIf>.equals(<StringLiteral stringCompare>)) <StatementNoShortIf stmtIf> else <Statement stmtElse>` => 
        (SwitchStatement) `switch (<Identifier idIf>) {<SwitchBlockStatementGroup switchBlock>}`
        when switchBlock := generateCaseFromIfElseStatement(stmtElse, idIf)
};

SwitchBlockStatementGroup generateCaseFromIfElseStatement(Statement stmt, Identifier idIf) = visit(stmt){
    case (StatementNoShortIf) `<StatementNoShortIf stmt1>` => 
         (SwitchBlockStatementGroup) `default: <BlockStatements stmt1>`

    case (IfThenElseStatement) `if (idIf.equals(<StringLiteral stringCompare>)) <StatementNoShortIf stmtIf> else <Statement stmtElse>` =>
         (SwitchBlockStatementGroup) `case <ConstantExpression stringCompare> : { <BlockStatements stmtIf> }`
};
```

However, when you run the refactoring code, the following error is displayed:

```
Expected SwitchBlockStatementGroup, but got Statement Advice: |http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Errors/Static/UnexpectedType/UnexpectedType.html|
```

At first, the refactoring is simple as can be seen in the code block below. Subsequently, I intend to increase its complexity to meet other cases.

```
if (string.equals("boo")){
    System.out.println("is a boo");
}
else if (string.equals("blah")){
    System.out.println("is a blah");
}
else if (string.equals("foo")){
    System.out.println("is a foo");
}
else{
    System.out.print("is a default");
}
```

Comment: you could simplify the grammar by using follow restrictions, i.e. `"if" "(" Expression "()" Statement !>> "else" Statement` removes the need for the StatementNoShortIf and you have fewer non-terminals/types to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem using (at the top level) a visitor + a recursive function based on a switch-case statement of Rascal (without using another visitor expression). Note that this code is still experimental, and I have only tested it using a few test cases.

```
CompilationUnit refactorToSwitchString(CompilationUnit unit) = top-down-break visit(unit) {
 case (Statement)`if(<Identifier id>.equals(<StringLiteral lit>)) {<Statement stmt1> } else <Statement stmt2>` => 
 (Statement)`switch(<Identifier id>) { case <StringLiteral lit> : { <Statement stmt1> }  <SwitchBlockStatementGroup* stmt3> }` 
 when stmt3 := buildSwitchGroups(stmt2, id)
};


SwitchBlockStatementGroups buildSwitchGroups(stmt, id) {
 switch(stmt) {
  case (Statement)`if(<Identifier id>.equals(<StringLiteral lit>)) { <Statement stmt1> } else <Statement stmt2>` : {
    stmt3 = buildSwitchGroups(stmt2, id) ;
    return (SwitchBlockStatementGroups)`case <StringLiteral lit> : { <Statement stmt1> break; } <SwitchBlockStatementGroup* stmt3>`;
  }
  case (Statement)`if(<Identifier id>.equals(<StringLiteral lit>)) <Statement stmt1>` : {
   return (SwitchBlockStatementGroups) `case <StringLiteral lit> : { <Statement stmt1> break;`;
  }
  case (Statement)`<Statement stmt>` : {
     return (SwitchBlockStatementGroups)`default : <Statement stmt>` ;
  }
};
```

I had to change the grammar a bit, introducing a definition like:

```
syntax SwitchBlock = "{" SwitchBlockStatementGroups SwitchLabel* "}" ;
syntax SwitchBlockStatementGroups = SwitchBlockStatementGroup* ;
```

Though I am not sure if this change was really necessary.

Answer (score 2):

In Rascal a visit statement can only replace a non-terminal by the same non-terminal.

- the reason is that in order for the rank-2 polymorphic semantics of the `visit` statement to type-check correctly, for all nodes it visits it can only replace the values of the type it finds there by another type which is a subtype of the matched type
- in this example `SwitchBlockStatementGroup` is not a sub-type of `StatementNoShortIf` which triggers the error message, and the same for `IfThenElseStatement` and `SwitchBlockStatementGroup`
- the specific error message is confusing
- the code as you have written it now would probably not generate correct Java code if the type-checker would have ignored it.
- if you use visit to transform a parse tree in Rascal, all intermediate results are guaranteed syntactically correct Java

So this means the code has to be fixed to jump through the type-safety and syntax-safety hoop. Options:

1. change the grammar to have fewer non-terminals; this can be done, but it is not easy to do correctly. It will make your life easier down the road. Rascal grammar use fewer non-terminals (i.e. only one `Statement` and one `Expression`), often supported by explicit disambiguation constructs (like priorities `>` and follow restrictions `!>>`). Also, we avoid the use chain rules (injections) like `syntax A = B` to avoid having to remember additional types and to avoid writing overly specific patterns.
2. zoom out to the `Statement` level and rewrite your pattern to replace one `Statement` by another `Statement`. In this case, this means matching the surrounding if-then-else on the left-hand side and rebuilding it on the right-hand side, and surrounding the `SwitchBlockStatementGroup` with the right brackets to make it a statement, etc.
3. I sometimes write reusable functions to translate between different sub-non-terminals.
4. The final workaround is to extend the grammar (in a separate module) with extensions to allow "incorrect" parse trees, and later transform them away or trust that they do coincide with correct Java. Examples I've seen are "BlockExpressions" where a block can be an expression temporarily during a source-to-source compiler only to be transformed away in a later stage to pure Java. I would not recommend this option in this case since the extended grammar is bound to be ambiguous.